# google translate using c# code

Tags: c#, google-translate

We have a website where in we need to translate this web site to artabic using google translate api. When I try doing this using c# back end code I'm getting this error when i make request with the api key uri .

error

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at    System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address);
```

I dont know where is the mistake can anyone help?

```
This is how my uri is formed    string l_strURL ="https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&source=en&target=ar&q=" + in_strString;   


 var in_string is the data to be translated
```

This is my code

```
        string l_strTranslation = in_strString;

        try
        {
            WebClient l_oWebClient = new WebClient();
            string l_strResult = "";

            //Notify the webclient we're expecting UTF-8
            l_oWebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;


            //l_oWebClient.Credentials = credentials;

           //l_oWebClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            l_strResult = l_oWebClient.DownloadString(l_strURL);
         }
```

Comment: Please commit your full code of the http request. I guess you missed to set some relevant http headers.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

> Is there any free quota? No, the Google Translate API is only
>   available as a paid service. Please see Pricing and Support for more
>   details. However we do offer the Google Website Translator gadget,
>   which will translate your website without charge.

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq

> I get an HTTP 403 error when I call the API. You may be exceeding your
>   quota: either the daily billable total, or the limit on request
>   characters per second. To view or change usage limits for your
>   project, or to request an increase to your total limit, do the
>   following:
>
> Go to the Google Cloud Console. Select a project. In the sidebar on
>   the left, select APIs & auth, then select an API. On the API's info
>   page, select the Quota link near the API name.

Comment: I'm trying to convert only one word dat's not translating. so I don't think it's something to do with quota .

Comment: e Google Translate API is only available as a paid service. did you pay?